# HP Proliant ML350 G5 - smart array initializing

Tags: windows-server-2003, hp-proliant, sas, hp-smart-array, raid-controller

I have a big problem with a HP ProLiant ML350 G5 with 2 SAS HDD 146GB.

It start with the message : "Slot 0 HP Smart Array E200i ... initializing" without any error message.
if I test the HDD with the Maintenance utility, it doesn't find any Disk !

I have changed the Mainboard, because I had an alert in the front of the tower, But both HDD were ok, with green lights. Now there aren't any lights in front of the disks.

The battery of the smart array have been changed 3 months ago

The RAID controller is in the motherboard

I can't find how to see or enter in the RAID configuration ? ctrl+S is for the ILO config.

Comment: Have you updated the firmware of the server, BIOS and Array controller?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I watched the drive lights, you can see as the raid controller detects each drive a light blinks on the drive.  I noticed the same hard drive was always being detected each time as the controller was stuck initialising. I pulled the offending drive and the server booted as normal. I then replaced the drive.